# How to do a true factory reset on surface pro 5?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation

I have a surface pro 5 that I bought for work and then they installed some software on it that allows me to VPN, restricts sign on options (no windows hello), prevents access to unknown local networks, etc.  I've decided to get a new system, and want to do a complete wipe of the surface so that I can use windows hello and all the other cool stuff.

I went thought the process of a 'factory reset' which is the only thing I can find online.  But after that was finished, I still see 'Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization' preventing me from changing my sign in options.  So there's still some work related software hanging out somewhere.

What do I need to do to absolutely nuke everything in bios or whatever that allows me to restore the system to the state it was in when it arrived in the box?

Comment: You can either use `Fresh Start` and/or `Reset` and choose not to keep your personal files.  If you cannot use either of those options you should update your question to reflect that fact.

Comment: reset will remove every thing in your system. So we could go to Settings\Update & security\recovery\Reset this PC to remove every thing. But the data located in other non system drive will be persists after reset.

Comment: The factory reset images can be found at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4023512 do they not solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Recovery Image from [Microsoft Surface Website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/surfacerecoveryimage).Select your surface pro model and enter your serial Key mentioned behind the microsoft surface logo and follow the instructions shown in the video.

**Tip:Make sure you have the following UEFI settings enabled as it was nowhere mentioned in the video.**

1. USB Booting Enabled.
2. Disable Boot Configuration Lock